# How to create a convertion mask based on numbers and charecter in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, mask

I need to create a mask formula in excel to convert what is NUMBER to "Y" and what is the character "." to "N". The origin data will be no more than seven characters in length.

> Example:
>
> **1.34567** to **YNYYYYY**
>
> **1.34..7** to **YNYYNNY**

Any recommendations? :-)

Comment: What have you tried? What is the dot? Is it the decimal separator? The Thousand separator? Why are there two dots in the last example? This cannot be a number.

Comment: @teylyn I think the 2 dots are an ellipses, so Frow didn't have to type the rest of the numbers; however, it should be "...". Frow, can you confirm this? Little typos or ambiguities like these make it hard for one to deduce the problem and answer your question.

Comment: @acarito I don't think so. The desired result replaces two dots with two N

Comment: The numbers are correspondents to the days of the week and the dots represents "no action" for that particular day. So for a register with "1234567", it means that I'd have "YYYYYYY" saying that for all days of the week I expect action. But I could also have "1.3.567" which would translate to "YNYNYYY" meaning that the action need to be trigged every day but Monday and Wednesday, considering the week starting on Sunday=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(LEN($A$1)>=1,IF(AND(CODE(MID($A$1,1,1))>47,CODE(MID($A$1,1,1))<58),"Y","N"),"")&IF(LEN($A$1)>=2,IF(AND(CODE(MID($A$1,2,1))>47,CODE(MID($A$1,2,1))<58),"Y","N"),"")&IF(LEN($A$1)>=3,IF(AND(CODE(MID($A$1,3,1))>47,CODE(MID($A$1,3,1))<58),"Y","N"),"")&IF(LEN($A$1)>=4,IF(AND(CODE(MID($A$1,4,1))>47,CODE(MID($A$1,4,1))<58),"Y","N"),"")&IF(LEN($A$1)>=5,IF(AND(CODE(MID($A$1,5,1))>47,CODE(MID($A$1,5,1))<58),"Y","N"),"")&IF(LEN($A$1)>=6,IF(AND(CODE(MID($A$1,6,1))>47,CODE(MID($A$1,6,1))<58),"Y","N"),"")&IF(LEN($A$1)>=7,IF(AND(CODE(MID($A$1,7,1))>47,CODE(MID($A$1,7,1))<58),"Y","N"),"")
```

TLDR : filter using code() & mid().

A bit of brute force there.. but that should work. Assuming your test cell is A1. and the code for 0-9 was identified manually.

Hope it solves. ( :

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I take your example and simplified a bit and use the following formula to sort out.

=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="1","Y","N")&IF(MID(A1,2,1)="2","Y","N")&IF(MID(A1,3,1)="3","Y","N")&IF(MID(A1,4,1)="4","Y","N")&IF(MID(A1,5,1)="5","Y","N")&IF(MID(A1,6,1)="6","Y","N")&IF(MID(A1,7,1)="7","Y","N")

Much appreciated!

Comment: I see.. it is a sequence of 1 to 7.. I though it was a random number.. Anyway.. wouldn't you be having a problem when the input is less that 7 characters/digit long?

Comment: Thank you for your concern  p._phidot_ but the input system, which is the data source, guarantee the input format. Cheers.

Comment: Would you mind to tick on my answer then? (to remove this question from the 'unanswered' list) ( :